# Null Pointer Exception when finding button on dialog

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

This is in my onCreate()

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.go_pro);
            Button free = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.still_free);
            free.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //EXCEPTION HERE!
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
```

this is int the layout go_pro:

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
     <Button android:id="@+id/still_free" android:text="Keep the ads" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></Button>
     <Button android:id="@+id/full_version" android:text="Go PRO" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
 </LinearLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.convert/com.convert.MainWindowYuval}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
**07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at com.convert.MainWindowYuval.onCreate(MainWindowYuval.java:93)**MY CLASS!!@#!@#!@#!@#!@#
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-09 16:23:40.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

EDIT: this is so wierd! i have two same buttons in my xml with different id and two buttons in the on create all the same but only one of them makes a null pointer exception

```
 Button button1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.full_version);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.paulmaidment.games.flagsoftheworld"));
                startActivity(intent);
                   dialog.cancel();//TODO OPEN PAID APP HERE!!!
                }
            });

            Button free = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stay_free);
            free.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //EXCEPTION ONLY HERE!
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Have you checked that `dialog.findViewById(R.id.still_free);` is returning somtheing different than null?

Comment: Make sure you clean and rebuild your project. It will re-index your id.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling findViewById on Dialog when it should be called on the Activity. Changing

```
        Button free = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.still_free);
```

to

```
        Button free = (Button) findViewById(R.id.still_free);
```

should fix it.

Comment: Not really. He is calling findViewById on the dialog cause he is searching for a button in the dialog. So that code is correct. (If I understand right what he wants to do)

Comment: when we customize any dailog, so we make xml according to need, i think he is use xml , and this xml part have a button ,

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your code

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.go_pro);
        Button free = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.still_free);
        free.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //EXCEPTION HERE!
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
```

to onCreate method of your Dialog class

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file the id is still_free and in your code you access stay_free... That is it

edit:
hmm in your edit you have stay_free but in the original post it is still_free so I assume you just changed the id to test if that caused it?